# Creating a button for Leaflet JS "panTo spot on map" outside of the map in Meteor

Tags: meteor, leaflet

I have created a map in **Meteor** using `Leaflet JS`. The problem is, I could only get `map.panTo` to work inside the `Template.dynamicmap.rendered` area. However, this makes it so anywhere you click on the map pans to the location.

This is the complete rendered area with id and access token removed.

```
Template.dynamicmap.rendered = function() {
  var southWest = L.latLng(35.02035919622158, -121.21049926757814);
  var northEast = L.latLng(42.4426214924114, -110.79740478515624);
  var mybounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
  var map = L.map('map_container',{zoomControl: false, maxBounds: [[37.00035919622158, -119.23049926757814],[40.4626214924114, -112.77740478515624]],}).setView([38.685509760012, -115.86181640625001], 10);
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  $('#map_container').css({width: w+'px', height: h+'px'});
  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
bounds: mybounds,
maxZoom: 10,
minZoom: 9,
}).addTo(map);
  L.Icon.Default.imagePath = 'packages/leaflet/images';
  var marker = L.marker([38.685509760012, -115.86181640625001]).addTo(map);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
};
```

So I tried putting it in an Template event shown below, this button is not within the map area but still in the dynamicmap template. It does not work though.

```
Template.dynamicmap.events({    
 'click input.goto3':(function() {
  map.panTo(L.latLng(38.685509760012, -115.86181640625001)); 
 })
});
```

I receive the error:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined"

in the console. Which I have been trying to wrap my head around but no luck. I was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction.

Here is my HTML Template.

```
<template name="dynamicmap">
<div class="containerbox">
<div class="map_container" id="map_container">
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="goto3" value="Go"/>
</template>
```

Comment: Are you able to post a bit more of the code. In particular the Template HTML, and the map definition.  My first only guess from the information here is that you have somehow structured your code, such that Template.dynamicmap.events and Template.dynamicmap.rendered end up in a different closure after Meteor bundle them.

Comment: @MultiMat I have updated the code with the template and full rendered area included. Thank you for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `map` a global variable:

```
var map = null;
Template.dynamicmap.rendered = function() {
  var southWest = L.latLng(35.02035919622158, -121.21049926757814);
  var northEast = L.latLng(42.4426214924114, -110.79740478515624);
  var mybounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
  map = L.map('map_container',{zoomControl: false, ...
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly it. Removing the variable from the rendered area and placing the variable on the outside worked.